# backslashes/escaping characters suddenly appears during transformation geopandas -> altair

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, altair

I'm trying to visualize some geodata in Altair. For the creation of the right dataformat, i use pandas and create the right dataformat.

```
for i in range(len(daten["gekoord"])):
 daten.iloc[i]["gekoord"] = '{"coordinates":'+ str(daten.iloc[i]["gekoord"]) +', "type": "Point"}'
```

Then i create the geopandasdataframe

```
staedte = gpd.GeoDataFrame(list(zip([eintrag for eintrag in daten["name"]],[eintrag for eintrag in daten["gekoord"]])), columns = ['name', 'geometry'])
```

In (Geo)Pandas, everything looks fine. The needed Data is in the geometry Series.
Snippet from exported csv below:

```
0,Gloucestershire,"{'coordinates':[51.83333, -2.16667], 'type': 'Point'}"
1,Derbyshire,"{'coordinates':[53.13543, -1.61125], 'type': 'Point'}"
2,Buxton,"{'coordinates':[53.25741, -1.90982], 'type': 'Point'}"
3,Halesowen,"{'coordinates':[52.44859, -2.04938], 'type': 'Point'}"
4,Wiltshire,"{'coordinates':[51.25, -1.91667], 'type': 'Point'}"
```

But if i transform the data in geopandas and trying to visualize it with Altair, i got a Error Message

> srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py:1350: UserWarning: Geometry column does not contain geometry.
> warnings.warn("Geometry column does not contain geometry.")

So i look up in the data, and there's an escaping backslash

```
        "name": "Gloucestershire",
        "geometry": "{\"coordinates\": [51.83333, -2.16667], \"type\": \"Point\"}"
      },
      {
        "name": "Derbyshire",
        "geometry": "{\"coordinates\": [53.13543, -1.61125], \"type\": \"Point\"}"
      },
      {
        "name": "Buxton",
        "geometry": "{\"coordinates\": [53.25741, -1.90982], \"type\": \"Point\"}"
      }
```

So i'm wondering, where does the escaping character come from? (the backslash, which probably messing my data up...)

Comment: You cannot use https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html#geopandas-points-from-xy?

Comment: This is not a fundamental solution, but if you specify geometry from the CSV file, it will become geometry information. `df = gpd.read_file('./test_geo.csv', GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES='geometry', KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS='NO')`